# Strange addEventListener behaviour

Tags: javascript, forms, input, listener

I'm working on a basic javascript form validation

```
var seUSer = document.getElementById("seUSername");
seUser.addEventListener("blur", validator(seUsername), false);

function validator (input) {
    if (input.value == "") {
        input.style.color="#fff";
    } else {
        input.style.color="#f0f0f0";
    }
}
```

In this case I'm expecting concrete input to change colour if it's value is empty after user has preformed "blur" action, so clicked away, but it changes colour on a page load i.e. without user doing anything, Is the "blur" action on the input by default? or what would be a right approach to handle this situation.

here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4K6D/

As you can see field is red from the beginning, but it should only be red if user un-focuses it and there is nothing in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
loginUsername.addEventListener("blur", validateForm(loginUsername), false);
```

is **calling** `validateForm` and passing the return value of it into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. You're not setting it up as an event handler.

To set up a function as an event handler, you don't *call* it, you just pass a reference to it. Since you want to give your function an argument, to do that in this case you'd wrap a function around it:

```
loginUsername.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    validateForm(loginUsername);
}, false);
```

Alternately, make your `validateForm` function work with `this` rather than the `input` argument:

```
document.getElementById("loginUsername").addEventListener("blur", validateForm, false);
// Note no (), we're not calling it ------------------------------------------^

function validateForm () {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.style.background="#f26060";
    } else {
        this.style.background="#fff";
    }
}
```

...because within the event handler hooked up via `addEventListener`, `this` is set to the element on which you hooked the event.

Comment: Indeed, it fixed the problem. Thank you. I'll accept answer as soon as so allows me.